# Can't retrieve data and display in iOS app

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to retrieve simple text data out of my database. When the app runs, you type in whatever you want and it saves it to the database. That part is working. When i log in to phpMyAdmin, that data is there. However, I'm trying to show the data as well, right above the textfield where the user inputs their text. When the app runs, there is nothing there. Here is my code for my retrieve data function. Thank you

```
func retrieveMessages(latestMessage:String) {

// Specify the URL of our retrieval web service
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://mypage.com/index.php")!

// Create a NSURLSession task with completion handler
let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in


    do {
        // Convert the json data into an array
        let dataArray:[AnyObject] = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [AnyObject]

        // Clear the messages array
        self.messagesArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        // Loop through each dictionary in the array
        for data in dataArray {

            let dictionary:[String:String] = data as! [String:String]

            // Append it to our messages array
            if dictionary["Text"] != nil {
                self.messagesArray.append(dictionary["Text"]!)
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            // Refresh the table
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    catch{}

})

// Run the task
task.resume()
```

}

Comment: Have you set the delegate and datasource of your tableView with ViewController.

Comment: Are you recieving any sort of data? try printing `data`

Comment: Also, maybe add a `prin()` in the `catch{}` block.

Comment: @Dravidian I'm receiving data when app runs and I input data. It populates the database and when I type the url in the browser the data is there and pulled correctly. Would I just say print(data) in the catch block??

Comment: EDIT last comment.....I meant I'm receiving data in the database but not in my app itself. No data shows up when I run the app